# Textpos: Let text end, instead of starting at specified coordinate

Tags: positioning, textpos

I am trying to fill out a pdf form using LaTeX with the package pdfoverlay and textpos.
[image: The problem]
When I specify a coordinate with textpos and give it some text, the text will start at the coordinate, but I want the end of the text to end at the coordinate (you can see on the picture I have specified a coordinate where the form ends, but instead of the text ending there it begins)

I have asked others about this and there was some confusion, someone thought I was trying to create a form, I am not, the underline and all is already part of the pdf I am filling out.

Comment: Note: I am open to any suggestions regarding a better method to do this so please be creative with solutions.

Comment: Try `\llap{AAAA}`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much Mr. Arseneau :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show what you are doing exactly, but if the left edge of the text is being placed where you want the right edge, then using `\llap{AAAA}` will put the right edge there. That probably looks like

```
\begin{textblock*}{some_width}(\hsize,vert_pos)
 \llap{AAAA}
\end{textblock*}
```

It is somewhat annoying that the textpos package only positions text *blocks* contained in the equivalent of \parbox. It would be nice to also have a type that was packaged like \makebox.

The \llap command (left overlap) comes from plain TeX, and it does not follow the paragraph parameters of the textblock, so the width parameter is irrelevant, as is the default centering performed by the textblock. (\llap is a bare \hbox, and goes on the vertical list instead of starting a paragraph.)

Alternatively, to do the job using the positioning parameters of textblock, you have to get a handle on the right edge of the text, and the easiest way is to push it to the right edge of the text block. So then

```
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}[1,1](\hsize,42mm)
  \raggedleft AAAAA
\end{textblock*}
```

The width (`\textwidth`) just has to be anything wider than the text. The `[1,` indicates positioning at the right edge of the text, and `\raggedleft` pushes the text to the right edge.

I would probably do

```
\newcommand\fillin[2]{% #1 = position, #2 = text
  \begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}[1,1](\hsize,#1)
     \raggedleft #2
  \end{textblock*}}
```

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I did. I already had a macro so I just added this to it. Thank you very much Mr. Arseneau. Have a good day.

Comment: @user224041 Remember to up-vote the answer you found helpful

Comment: @donald-arsenau The positioned `\makebox` is an interesting idea. What would that look like? `\makeboxat(x,y){text}` springs to mind?  Or `\begin{textbox}(x,y)text\end{textbox}` for consistency?

Comment: Mr. Gray, I'm afraid I can't do that. I am not a properly registered user, but I am considering registration, need to finish reading the Terms of Service first when I have spare time.

Answer (score 0):

See the textpos manual, Sect.1.3.3 *Choosing the textblock reference point*:

> You may give an optional argument to the {textblock} environment, specifying which point in the box is to be placed at the specified point:

```
\begin{textblock}{⟨hsize⟩}[⟨ho⟩,⟨vo⟩](⟨hpos⟩,⟨vpos⟩)
text...
\end{textblock}
```

> The coordinates `⟨ho⟩` and `⟨vo⟩` are fractions of the width and height of the text box, respectively, and state that the box is to be placed so that the reference point `(⟨ho⟩,⟨vo⟩)` within the box is to be placed at the point `(⟨hpos⟩,⟨vpos⟩)` on the page. The default specification is `[0,0]`, indicating the top left of the box; the argument `[0,1]` (for example) would specify the bottom left, and `[0.5,0.5]` the middle.

There are further details, including how to default this, later in that section.

Comment: So actually, I did read through the manual many times before and found this section: I tried using this but I think its a misinterpretation of the text because actually, this is only defining where on the coordinate it should *start* and nothing about the text finishing there. The answer by Mr. Arseneau that I should use \llap produces the *exact* result that I wanted.

Comment: Note that `\begin{textblock}{2}[1,1](3,3) AAAA\end{textblock}` will indeed produce a block 2 modules wide, with its bottom right corner at (3,3) _but_ the text `AAAA` will be at the left-hand side of the block, ie, not at (3,3).  You might want to say `\hfill AAAA` (or equivalent), which will put the text at the right of the box, at (3,3). The option `[showboxes]` might make it easier to position your text. (It _might_ also be the case that you're using an old version of the package: the documentation notes that this feature was inconsistently implemented before v1.8).